# How to implement a "NOT" operator for if IE Condition

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements

If you do

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<link rel ... >
<![endif]-->
```

other browsers will still think this section is commented out. How do I make other browsers see the stylesheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this ...

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel= ...
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Basically you want to close the comments, without closing the the IE specific conditional section. It remains just normal HTML to other browsers, while becoming an exclusion zone for IE.